# Error while loading skimage camera images

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I was trying [a crash course on NumPy for images](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/numpy_images.html#numpy) and this line threw an error:

```
>> from skimage import data
>> camera = data.camera()
```

Following is the error trace of the same:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8539ecc9e129> in <module>
----> 1 data.camera()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/data/__init__.py in camera()
    107         Camera image.
    108     """
--> 109     return _load("camera.png")
    110 
    111 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/data/__init__.py in _load(f, as_gray)
     94     # we lazy import it here
     95     from ..io import imread
---> 96     return imread(_os.path.join(data_dir, f), plugin='pil', as_gray=as_gray)
     97 
     98 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/io/_io.py in imread(fname, as_gray, plugin, **plugin_args)
     46 
     47     with file_or_url_context(fname) as fname:
---> 48         img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
     49 
     50     if not hasattr(img, 'ndim'):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py in call_plugin(kind, *args, **kwargs)
    208                                (plugin, kind))
    209 
--> 210     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    211 
    212 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py in imread(fname, dtype, img_num, **kwargs)
     34         with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
     35             im = Image.open(f)
---> 36             return pil_to_ndarray(im, dtype=dtype, img_num=img_num)
     37     else:
     38         im = Image.open(fname)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py in pil_to_ndarray(image, dtype, img_num)
     64     while 1:
     65         try:
---> 66             image.seek(i)
     67         except EOFError:
     68             break

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py in seek(self, frame)
    737 
    738     def seek(self, frame):
--> 739         if not self._seek_check(frame):
    740             return
    741         if frame < self.__frame:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py in _seek_check(self, frame)
    304             raise EOFError("attempt to seek outside sequence")
    305 
--> 306         return self.tell() != frame
    307 
    308 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py in tell(self)
    825 
    826     def tell(self):
--> 827         return self.__frame
    828 
    829     def load_prepare(self):

AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute '_PngImageFile__frame'
```

What is the problem here? I'm using **skimage 0.16.2**, **Python 3.6.9** on **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**.

I have plenty of experience with Scikit-Learn but a newbie to image processing and skimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error with the latest release of Pillow (7.1.0). They have been [rushing to fix it](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4509) and you should soon be able to fix the problem by doing `pip install -U Pillow`. Monitor [this page](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#history) for the next release after 7.1.

You can also install the previous version, `pip install Pillow==7.0.0`.